# Node.js won't recognise an Express object & I can't set paths to my CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

Express as in - http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

I'm using sockets.io:

```
const PORT = 3000;
var objServer = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(objServer);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//objServer.use(express.static("public"));

objServer.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index_test.html');
});

//node http server started
http.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:' + PORT);
});
```

It loads the HTML page, but none of the CSS or JS files included in the html head tag.  Here's how the head tag currently looks, but I've pretty much exhausted different notations and paths and locations, and nothing has worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>OFC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ofctest.css">
    <script src="public/ofc.js"></script>
    <script src="public/ofc_JS_classes.js"></script>
    <script src="public/play.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="table">
        <p>some stuff</p>
    </div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I uncomment out `objServer.use(express.static("public"));` to try and set a path of some sort, it fails to recognise "express".  I'll edit in the error message in second.

Edit: here's the error message in the terminal:

```
objServer.use(express.static("public"));
              ^

ReferenceError: express is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Something\index.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why `objServer.use(express.static("public"));` is commented ?

Comment: Because it crashes if I try and use it.

Answer (score 1):

There is standard code given by express framework.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
 console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

you can refere this URL : http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

As i see in you code you have initialize express (`called constructor : express()`) in one line of code like

```
var objServer = require('express')();
```

which is equivalent to

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
```

so eventually your `app` becomes `objServer`

`express.static` is built-in middleware function in Express.

you were getting an error because of you have taken variable `objServer` instead of `express`. 
so you have to use `objServer` whenever you encountered a keyword `express`

Comment: Yeah, the other answer pointed that out.  I still can't serve up JS and CSS by file in the html head tag, though.  Any ideas how I get that to work?

Comment: check removing public from script tag like
 `<script src="/ofc.js"></script>`
@erv

Answer (score 0):

use this for `express is not defined`

```
objServer.use(objServer.static("public"));
```

and for give specific path use this

```
app.use("/css", objServer.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.use("/js", objServer.static(__dirname + '/public/js'));
```

here `/app/css` is your `public` folder full path
now you can '/css' and '/js' for .js files directly

Comment: ok, cheers.  That's got rid of the error, now I need to know how to serve up my CSS and JS files in the html head.  Any idea how you represent the paths correctly?

Comment: @erv and give high rate to my ans

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense.  There is no 'app' variable; and I'm not trying to serve up fonts; nor does my directory structure look anything like that.

Comment: @erv where is your css files are??

Comment: in the /public directory.  It's one level down from the directory that my index.js sits in.  And can you sort out the confusion in the answer?  Why have you got both my objServer variable and some new 'app' variable??

Comment: @erv now see it

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer still doesn't make any sense to me.  For the third time, there is no "app" variable.  Where are you getting it from?  And I can't follow what you mean by those paths.  Why is the path /app/assets/ in there??

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now.  Here's a minimal code working version:
index.js

```
const PORT = 3000;
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
const http = require("http").Server(server);
const path = require("path");
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")));
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/css"));
server.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/js"));

http.listen(PORT, function() {
      console.log("server listening on port " + PORT);
});

io.on("connection", function(socket){
      console.log("user connected");
});
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
      <title>test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css">
      <script src="js/test.js"></script>
      <script src="js/test_2.js"></script>+
</head>

<body>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <p>testing some text</p>
      <input type="button" onclick="stuff()" value="button 1">
      <input type="button" onclick="btn2()" value="button 2">

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
      var socket = io();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

All CSS and Scripts load now.  My directory structure is:

[image]

with CSS and JS files (other than index.js, of course) directly in their respective folders.